Revisiting the Trolley Problem
In philosophy, the trolley problem presents a moral dilemma: you can either take action to divert a runaway trolley, saving five people but causing the death of one person, or do nothing, allowing the trolley to kill the five but sparing the one. Many argue that it is morally justified to divert the trolley, prioritizing the greater number of lives saved. However, isn't it morally problematic to actively interfere and cause the death of an innocent person who otherwise would have survived naturally?
If we choose not to act, the deaths of the five individuals occur without our intervention, and the one person survives as a result of natural events. But if we intervene, we are directly responsible for the death of the one individual.
How should this moral dilemma be resolved? Is it ethically preferable to avoid interference and let events unfold naturally, or does the moral obligation to save the greater number justify sacrificing one life? Additionally, what is your perspective on the matter?

Please name all the accounts you have previously posted under. Thank you

“what is your perspective” - does that make this question opinion-based? People’s resolution depends on their specific philosophy.

@JonathanZ - I may not be picking up all relevant signals in this post. What triggered your question?

@mudskipper - "What is your perspective....?" is a verbal tic of one user who is constantly making new accounts. I know some people here think that we should only engage with the text of the posted question, but I believe that we are a community of a sort, and people having identities and reputations help make that community better.

Voting to close this. The question does not add a specific focus and does not show any study so it's unclear why the wiki article about the problem would not answer the OPs question or why the problem needs "revisiting".

You need to define "naturally" and how or why it matters.

It's a no win scenario. You're not going to solve it unless you think outside of the box (usually not permitted in this though experiment), so the best possible outcome is not solving the problem but just doing the least amount of harm.
Which in itself is less of a straight forward analysis and more of a judgement call. So "resolving" the dilemma usually consists of picking certain moral priorities and taking a look at how they play out with regards to the example.
So idk you might give a human life a fixed value, then 5 > 1 and therefore you might save 5. Or you might give human lives an infinite value then 5 inf = 1 inf. Or you assume that those who survive will suffer from survivor guilt or you might just hate people, then -5x < -1x.
Or sure you could argue with "doing vs allowing", so is doing active harm worse than enabling passive harm? Where you could argue that not allowing any harm to happen, might be a praiseworthy ideal, but ultimately unrealistic as there is so much harm being done at any moment that you'd not be realistically able to prevent it and that you'd also have to sustain yourself to be able to help in the first place or whether your own life is worth more or less than other people and whatnot.
But also none of that matters in this problem, where acting or no acting is the only thing you can do an has no tangible effect on yourself. Also while you could argue that pulling the lever actually dooms someone making you the cause of their death rather than just "not helping". Would you actually feel a practical difference? Like would you actually make this distinction? Like in either case this is, as said, no win. No matter what you do or not do people are going to die because of unknown causes outside of your responsibility. Yet despite not being responsible for the scenario who dies very much is your responsibility because you had the option to make a choice and I'm not sure you'd be able to set that thought to rest no matter what option you would have picked.
Unless you act instinctively not realize there's another person on the other track or something like that and act in good consciousness and the kill is just an accident. However that's not an option, you know the deal, no outside of the box thinking.
Also that scenario has already been discussed, to my knowledge it's something like "the fat man scenario". So what if the trolley runs below a bridge and you could push a particularly big individual infront of the trolley so that the trolley is stopped but the person most definitely dies in the process. In that case you'd need to literally kill an innocent person to save the 5.
It doesn't meaningfully change the scenario unlike that it makes the killing more immediate. So the further it is away the more you might rationalize it in he abstract, the closer you'd have to grapple with it on a more direct intimate layer. Though ultimately it's still a thought experiment and still in the abstract...
And in reality probably some instinct will save you in that you either do something or can't get yourself to do something and can blame it upon actionism or freezing and no sane jurisdiction would blame you either way or if they do you wouldn't have been able to avoid that anyway.
Also one might ask oneself the question as to whether it would be a good idea to extrapolate one's ethical and moral principles from a scenario where all possible options sucks and where no matter what option your prefer for whatever reason, the outcome still sucks.
